# Retorno de função -0

Tags: c++, c++17

Criei uma classe Polinômio, dentre as funções membros presentes em minha classe existe a função de resolução de raízes. Caso o grau do polinômio seja 2, utilizo baskhara para resolução. Porém percebi que caso a raiz seja única e 0 uma delas fica como 0 e a outra - 0. Já fiz essa função várias vezes e essa é a primeira vez que vejo algo do tipo.

Comment: Tem que colocar o código na pergunta, caso contrário apenas podemos tentar adivinhar o que você efetivamente fez.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O ideal seria você ter colocado um código de exemplo. Mas provavelmente você está usando números de ponto flutuante (float ou double) e eles têm dois zeros: +0 e -0. São úteis para preservar o sinal em casos-limite do tipo -1.0/10e400.